# POSKeyError: ‘No blob file’ using api.content.copy

Tags: plone, dexterity, plone-5.x

I'm trying to copy objects from a collection into a folder.  Each collection consists of documents, files, and images. When I ran the script, it throws the **POSKeyError** exception.

[image]

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Hopefully not stating the obvious, but you are missing a blob in your source object, or a content object within it.  Is your source database correctly configured to find the blobstorage?  How are you running this (e.g. a runscript?).  You will need to use the oid (I assume this is in the traceback) of the object referencing the blob to figure out which object is missing a blob in a debug session using >>> app._p_jar.get(oid)

Comment: i think the oid is not printed in the traceback - but you can use Products.PDBDebugMode which will give you a pdb console after the error occured. there you can call
>>> print oid

and do what @sdupton suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the blob file is not available in the file-system, there is no way to fix this, except restore from backup.

With https://pypi.python.org/pypi/experimental.gracefulblobmissing the missing file is ignored.